# Do Google differentiate Gmail accounts based on top-level domain?

Tags: gmail

I have a friend in Europe that I am trying to e-mail. Does it matter that I sent my message to [username]@gmail.com rather than [username]@gmail.rs ?

Answer (score 3):

gmail.rs does not exist as a mail server.
Eventhough there are google.com, google.rs, etc. Gmail is always gmail.com

Comment: While true for `.rs`, some other Gmail TLDs do have a mail entry in the DNS: `host gmail.nl` yields `gmail.nl mail is handled by 10 bh.markmonitor.com`. Still then, your answer is right, of course.